# Why do pods with completed status still show up in kubctl get pods?

Tags: kubernetes

I have executed the samples from the book "Kubernetes Up and Running" where a pod with a work queue is run, then a k8s job is created 5 pods to consume all the work on the queue. I have reproduced the yaml api objects below.

My Expectation is that once a k8s job completes then it's pods would be deleted but `kubectl get pods -o wide` shows the pods are still around even though it reports 0/1 containers ready and they still seem to have ip addresses assigned see output below.

- When will completed job pods be removed from the output of `kubectl get pods` why is that not right after all the containers in the pod finish?
- Are the pods consuming any resources when they complete like an IP address or is the info being printed out historical?

Output from kubectl after all the pods have consumed all the messages.

```
kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME              READY     STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE       IP           NODE
consumers-bws9f   0/1       Completed   0          6m        10.32.0.35   gke-cluster1-default-pool-3796b2ee-rtcr
consumers-d25cs   0/1       Completed   0          6m        10.32.0.33   gke-cluster1-default-pool-3796b2ee-rtcr
consumers-jcwr8   0/1       Completed   0          6m        10.32.2.26   gke-cluster1-default-pool-3796b2ee-tpml
consumers-l9rkf   0/1       Completed   0          6m        10.32.0.34   gke-cluster1-default-pool-3796b2ee-rtcr
consumers-mbd5c   0/1       Completed   0          6m        10.32.2.27   gke-cluster1-default-pool-3796b2ee-tpml
queue-wlf8v       1/1       Running     0          22m       10.32.0.32   gke-cluster1-default-pool-3796b2ee-rtcr
```

The follow three k8s api calls were executed these are cut and pasted from the book samples.

Run a pod with a work queue

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  labels:
    app: work-queue
    component: queue
    chapter: jobs
  name: queue
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: work-queue
        component: queue
        chapter: jobs
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: queue
        image: "gcr.io/kuar-demo/kuard-amd64:1"
        imagePullPolicy: Always
```

Expose the pod as a service so that the worker pods can get to it.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: work-queue
    component: queue
    chapter: jobs
  name: queue
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: work-queue
    component: queue
```

Post 100 items to the queue then run a job with 5 pods executing in parallel until the queue is empty.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  labels:
    app: message-queue
    component: consumer
    chapter: jobs
  name: consumers
spec:
  parallelism: 5
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: message-queue
        component: consumer
        chapter: jobs
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: worker
        image: "gcr.io/kuar-demo/kuard-amd64:1"
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        args:
        - "--keygen-enable"
        - "--keygen-exit-on-complete"
        - "--keygen-memq-server=http://queue:8080/memq/server"
        - "--keygen-memq-queue=keygen"
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Answer (score 27):

The [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/) say it pretty well:

> When a Job completes, no more Pods are created, but the Pods are not
>   deleted either. Keeping them around allows you to still view the logs
>   of completed pods to check for errors, warnings, or other diagnostic
>   output. The job object also remains after it is completed so that you
>   can view its status. It is up to the user to delete old jobs after
>   noting their status. Delete the job with kubectl (e.g. kubectl delete
>   jobs/pi or kubectl delete -f ./job.yaml). When you delete the job
>   using kubectl, all the pods it created are deleted too.

Comment: What are resources are still being consumed by the pods? Clearly not any memory / cpu since the pod's containers are not running so what other resources are still being consumed by letting the pod hang around?

Comment: @ams Did you find the answer to this question? Also, can we view the logs of evicted pods?

Comment: I do see [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#clean-up-finished-jobs-automatically) word of caution about completed jobs:
"Finished Jobs are usually no longer needed in the system. Keeping them around in the system will put pressure on the API server."

Comment: @ams entries in the etcd database.

Answer (score 4):

It shows **completed** status when it is actually terminated. If you set **restartPolicy:Never (when you don't want to run more than once)** then it goes to this state.

Terminated: Indicates that the container **completed** its execution and has stopped running. A container enters into this when it has successfully completed execution or when it has failed for some reason. Regardless, a reason and exit code is displayed, as well as the container’s start and finish time. Before a container enters into Terminated, preStop hook (if any) is executed.

...
State:          Terminated
Reason:       **Completed**
Exit Code:    0
Started:      Wed, 30 Jan 2019 11:45:26 +0530
Finished:     Wed, 30 Jan 2019 11:45:26 +0530
...